# How to get the html filed value in php

Tags: php, html, hidden-field

I have made an hidden html field 
`<input type="hidden" name="t" id="t" value="something">`

```
<? // value here?>
```

How I can get this value with out submitting the page

Comment: I dont understand. if this input is being created server side you should already have the value there. If you are trying to get it off a client side created input box youll need to post it back to the server

Comment: this filed is created from the response of an request from external server

Comment: probably author looks somethind like javascript document.getElementById('t').value

Comment: You already have the value.  In your example, the value is `something`.  When you build that field in the page response, whatever value you use to set that is the value of the field.  If it came from a database, you have it in the database.  If it came from session state, you have it in session state.  Etc.  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Response, but by whom? Is code related? If so, please post it. Your question is just totally not clear what you would like to know, there are many ways to obtain that value (as it's already there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. PHP is server side. This means, PHP's job is finished as soon the page finished loading.

You could send the form value to your PHP script with AJAX, which would be in the background - no submitting or refreshing needed.

Edit: Did you mean to ask, how you can get the value for your hidden input after the page was generated?

Answer (score 3):

> How I can get this value with out submitting the page

You can't get its value in PHP without submitting your from, use JavaScript instead to get its value.

**Example:**

```
alert(document.getElementById('t').value);
```

Comment: Maybe worth expanding your answer to include the possibility of jquery? It would probably help the author.

Comment: Why would jQuery help, if the answer is a __one__ line of code??